# Failed experiment on career

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm currently seeing this on the careers homepage. You probably already know, but just making sure.

[image: failed experiment]

Comment: I laughed at the title. +1 ;)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for pointing this out. It'll be resolved on our next build.